# I am trying to add a table to a cell in an already created table in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I am creating a table using asp.net code behind. The purpose of this table is for layout. PLEASE DON'T TELL ME THAT THIS IS NOT THE PROPER WAY TO DO IT. I am being forced to do it by another programmer. I then use the routine to create a table and assign datatable values and add this table to one of the cells I created earlier. When I use `obj.Controls.Add(tbl)` to add the table. When I run it tells me that `tbl` is probably null and I know that it is not. Any ideas?

```
 Public Sub CreateTable()
    Dim tbl As Table
    Dim tbl1 As Table
    Dim tr As TableRow
    Dim tc As TableCell
    Dim objVolume As New DBAdult.VOLUME
    Dim objDeleteAFile As New DBAdult.DeleteAFile
    Dim maxSeqNum As Int16
    Dim maxLocSeqNum As Int16
    Dim tblCounter As Int16
    Dim rowCounter As Int16
    Dim cellCounter As Int16
    Dim containerTable As Table
    Dim dt As DataTable
    Dim dr As DataRow
    Dim cc As TableCell
    Dim dtTable As Table
    Dim numCells As Long
    Dim VolLocHistInfo1 As String
    Dim VolLocHistInfo2 As String
    Dim VolLocHistInfo3 As String
    Dim VolLocHistInfo4 As String
    Dim insertCell As TableCell
    Dim obj As TableCell

    tbl = VolLocHistInfoContainer
    maxSeqNum = objVolume.GetMaxBarcodeNum(fileID, 8)
    maxLocSeqNum = objVolume.GetMaxVolLocSeqNum(fileID)
    dt = objDeleteAFile.dbAdultVolLocHist(fileID)
    Dim x As Integer
    x = dt.Rows.Count
    For Each dr In dt.Rows
        tbl = New Table
        tr = New TableRow
        tc = New TableCell
        tc.Attributes.Add("runat", "server")
        tc.Style("Border-Color") = "#000000"
        tc.Style("Border-Style") = "Solid"
        tc.Style("Border-Width") = "1pt"
        tc.Style("width") = "65%"
        tc.Style("background-color") = "#E9E9E9"
        tc.Text = "Volume Barcode Number"
        tr.Cells.Add(tc)
        tc = New TableCell
        tc.Attributes.Add("runat", "server")
        tc.Style("Border-Color") = "#000000"
        tc.Style("Border-Style") = "Solid"
        tc.Style("Border-Width") = "1pt"
        tc.Style("width") = "35%"
        tc.Text = dr(1).ToString()
        tr.Cells.Add(tc)
        tbl.Rows.Add(tr)
        '******************************************************************************************

        tr = New TableRow
        tc = New TableCell
        tc.Attributes.Add("runat", "server")
        tc.Style("Border-Color") = "#000000"
        tc.Style("Border-Style") = "Solid"
        tc.Style("Border-Width") = "1pt"
        tc.Style("width") = "65%"
        tc.Style("background-color") = "#E9E9E9"
        tc.Text = "Archive  Location"
        tr.Cells.Add(tc)
        tc = New TableCell
        tc.Attributes.Add("runat", "server")
        tc.Style("Border-Color") = "#000000"
        tc.Style("Border-Style") = "Solid"
        tc.Style("Border-Width") = "1pt"
        tc.Style("width") = "35%"
        tc.Text = dr(2).ToString()
        tr.Cells.Add(tc)
        tbl.Rows.Add(tr)
        '******************************************************************************************

        tr = New TableRow
        tc = New TableCell
        tc.Attributes.Add("runat", "server")
        tc.Style("Border-Color") = "#000000"
        tc.Style("Border-Style") = "Solid"
        tc.Style("Border-Width") = "1pt"
        tc.Style("width") = "65%"
        tc.Style("background-color") = "#E9E9E9"
        tc.Text = "Storage Type"
        tr.Cells.Add(tc)
        tc = New TableCell
        tc.Attributes.Add("runat", "server")
        tc.Style("Border-Color") = "#000000"
        tc.Style("Border-Style") = "Solid"
        tc.Style("Border-Width") = "1pt"
        tc.Style("width") = "35%"
        tc.Text = dr(3).ToString()
        tr.Cells.Add(tc)
        tbl.Rows.Add(tr)
        '******************************************************************************************

        tr = New TableRow
        tc = New TableCell
        tc.Attributes.Add("runat", "server")
        tc.Style("Border-Color") = "#000000"
        tc.Style("Border-Style") = "Solid"
        tc.Style("Border-Width") = "1pt"
        tc.Style("width") = "65%"
        tc.Style("background-color") = "#E9E9E9"
        tc.Text = "Note"
        tr.Cells.Add(tc)
        tc = New TableCell
        tc.Attributes.Add("runat", "server")
        tc.Style("Border-Color") = "#000000"
        tc.Style("Border-Style") = "Solid"
        tc.Style("Border-Width") = "1pt"
        tc.Text = dr(4).ToString()
        tc.Style("width") = "35%"
        tr.Cells.Add(tc)
        tbl.Rows.Add(tr)
        '******************************************************************************************

        obj = Page.FindControl("AdultVolLocHistContainer")
        obj.Controls.Add(tbl)
    Next
END SUB
```

Comment: Can you explain what this is:  tbl = VolLocHistInfoContainer ? If you could add the actual error text that would be useful as well.

Comment: Please, edit your question and add exact error message. Also, verify that this line: `obj = Page.FindControl("AdultVolLocHistContainer")` is finding the control.

Comment: Also, you seem to be saying that you know more than .NET does about what is null and what is not. I don't think so. Instead, I suggest you assume that .NET is not lying to you, then proceed to ask yourself what it would take for .NET to be telling you the truth.

Comment: in order for obj = Page.FindControl("AdultVolLocHistContainer")
to work, AdultVolLocHistContainer needs to be a top level element. You might consider using a recursive method: http://blog.codinghorror.com/recursive-pagefindcontrol/